# Is it better to place data and associated tasks in Fragment or Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, on entering an Activity, an background task is started to get data from the server, and the data would be displayed in a Fragment. There are 3 ways to do it.

1. Start the task in `Activity.onCreate()`, and keep the data as the field of Acitivity, and then create the Fragment. The Fragment gets the reference of data to be displayed from the Activity, which implements a `FragmentListener` interface. All data are saved in `Acitivity.onSavedInstance()`. The Fragment keeps no data itself and is only used to display.

2. Start the task in `Activity.onCreate()`, but keep the data as the field of Fragment. All data are saved in `Fragment.onSavedInstance()`.

3. All related work is done in Fragment. The code of data getting is also placed in the Fragment. So in the Activity, only the creation of Fragment is called. It's easy to put the Fragment into a different Activity when needed in this way.

I want to know which way is the best way to design the app, considering the rules of decoupling, modularization and extension in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can include all the code entirely in the fragment and not even need the Activity to know it exists or care about it other than initially starting the fragment. It would seem that keeping everything in the Fragment would be best. Then you could just have that fragment and reuse it for any activity you wanted, which is the goal of good decoupling (even if you don't have that goal).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this design patter:

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it in the Fragmant, as long as the Fragmant is the only place I'll use it in.

However, say you have two Fragmants and they both use the data, then the logical thing to do is to keep the data in a common place; i.e. the Activity.